# Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12

Tags: jquery, html, webkit, domexception

I got the error 'Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12' with this code:

```
var html = '<table><tr><td></td><td><input type="text" name="textArea" value="some text" /></td></tr></table>';
$(this.propertyContainer).html(html)
```

But **NOT** with this code:

```
$(this.propertyContainer).html('<table><tr><td></td><td><input type="text" name="textArea" value="some text" /></td></tr></table>')
```

Here is the html of propertyContainer:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="property-grid" style="position: absolute; top: 35px; left: 0px;" id="ext-gen126"></div>
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: `this` is an object, it's not very important, it contains `propertyContainer` which I specify

Comment: Exception 12 is a syntax error, are you sure the propertyContainer value is valid?

Comment: I guess yes: $(this.propertyContainer)
[
<div class=​"property-grid" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 35px;​ left:​ 0px;​" id=​"ext-gen126">​</div>​
]

Comment: I edited the body, I don't get any error when I pass the string directly (without html variable)

Comment: What happens when you defined `var propertyContainer=$("#ext-gen126");`. As far as you say this other `propertyContainer` references the same element so it should be the same. Does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't work: $("#ext-gen126").html(html); gives Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. I forgot the character '/' at the end of the input tag...

I guess it's because of the dtd:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 plus SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/2002/04/xhtml-math-svg/xhtml-math-svg.dtd"
>
```

Sorry for that...

Answer (score 1):

No error here: http://jsfiddle.net/PA4Eg/

Possible mistake is one with the context, I guess (the meaning of `this`).

The source:

```
var obj = {
        propertyContainer: document.getElementById('ext-gen126')
    },
    html = '<table><tr><td></td><td><input type="text" name="textArea" value="some text" /></td></tr></table>';

$(obj.propertyContainer).html(html);
​
```

In the example bellow my source is the same:

```
var obj = {
        propertyContainer: document.getElementById('ext-gen126')
    },
    html = '<table><tr><td></td><td><input type="text" name="textArea" value="some text" /></td></tr></table>';

setHtml.call(obj, html);

function setHtml(html) {
    $(this.propertyContainer).html(html);
}
​
```

I use function to set the HTML content of the given div. For this function I use `obj` as context. It works again. I hope you'll fix your code by comparing it with the one above.