# Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12 on Tag Creation Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, syntax-error, dtd

I have the following javascript:

```
var orderItemQuantity = $('<input/>', {
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'order_detail[][quantity]',
    value: itemQuantity
});
```

The above javascript throws the following error message:

```
Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12
```

This one works without error:

```
var newListItem = $('<li/>', {
    html:
    $('#item_name_'+itemId).text() +
    '(' + $('#item_quantity_' + itemId).val() +')' +
    '<a onclick="removeItem(' + itemId + ')">Delete this</a>' +
    '<input type="hidden" name="order_detail[][item_id]" value="' + itemId + '"/>',
    id: itemId
});
```

I checked the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950930/error-syntax-err-dom-exception-12) but the answer did not specify clearly the correct reason WHY.

Here is my DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

**Question**: Why does `$('<input/>')` and `$('<input>')` throw the said exception while `$('<li/>')` is not a problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you have jQuery loaded in your first example.

Even if you don't have jQuery loaded, the function `$()` is now defined by Google Chrome as something similar to `querySelectorAll()`.

This function only accepts a CSS selector as parameter and not arbitrary HTML like jQuery's `$()`.

From the docs:

> SYNTAX_ERR code 12 In invalid or illegal string has been specified;
>   for example setting the selectorText    property of a CSSStyleRule
>   with an invalid CSS value.

The function is expecting a CSS selector and you gave it HTML so it gave a syntax error.

See this fiddle, it works just fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/S6d6w/